# no commands defined in the “setup” namespace

Tags: magento-2.1

[InvalidArgumentException]
  There are no commands defined in the "cache" namespace.
[image]

I am using putty to run some commands. if I run
php bin/magento setup:cache
Is there any thing I missed during installation

Comment: which command you are trying ?

Comment: Php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: I uploaded all files on server then I run upgrade and cache flush commands using putty. it showing me above error.

Comment: once check with php bin/magento list, Is it showing all commands ?

Comment: go through this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122574/there-are-no-commands-defined-in-the-cache-namespace)

Comment: Have you got solution?

Answer (score 1):

**Please run below commands**

```
rm -Rf var/cache/* generated/*
```

**then**

```
php -f bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

The general main cause of this kind of error is missing `etc/module.xml` file in your module. Or, missing s`etup_version` code in`module.xml` file.

Here is a sample `module.xml` file of a module named `YourNamespace_YourModule`.

> app/code/YourNamespace/YourModule/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--    
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Moddule/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Namespace_Yourmodule" setup_version="1.5.0">

</module>
```

If you are not sure which module is creating this problem, you can try removing each module and check to find the problematic module.

**Solution 2:**

If solution 1 doesn’t help then you can try this second solution.

Give full control (read/write/execute) to var and pub directory solved this issue for me.

> sudo chmod -R 777 var pub

You may also try running the following command:

> sudo php -f bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content
>   YourNamespace_YourModule

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that the **module.xml** file is defined properly in the **etc** directory of your module.

Then, run these commands in the root directory

```
rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/* pub/static/*
php bim/magento cache:clean
php bim/magento cache:flush
```

edit:

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: Please update your answer, it is **bin** not **bim**

Answer (score 0):

Seems some modules without file **etc/module.xml**

and this create error in command line

Answer (score 0):

This also happens to me sometimes in sandbox env due to a wrong server configuration and not a code issue as mentionned in the others responses.

- Sending a magento command in CLI
- Getting the no command defined error as a result for an unknown reason.

When this happens if it's not a code issue, I run `composer install` to properly reinstall magento and after that the command CLI works again as expected.

Answer (score 0):

No solution worked for me, removed var/* generated/* but one solution worked,
that is i **reinstall magento** using cmd. and it fixed all the issues.
hope this help for fresh installion

Comment: that's what composer install does though :)