# I made clone of Magento 2.2.4 Enterprise edition from Integration branch but gives error There are no commands defined in the “cache” namespace

Tags: magento2, magento2-enterprise

- I made clone of Magento 2.2.4 Enterprise edition from Integration
  branch.
- `php version 7.1.23`
- `Magento 2.2.4` **Enterprise edition** (Cloud)

On running command `php bin/magento cache:flush`

> There are no commands defined in the “cache” namespace

I have tried

```
rm -Rf var/cache/*
rm -Rf var/generation/*
```

and this command working fine

```
php bin/magento
```

Comment: i ran that, and no error

Comment: can you go through [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/122993/55928) one

Comment: Try to run "setup:upgrade command, have got error like this `There are no commands defined in the “setup” namespace`?

Comment: yes, i already did

Comment: yes i refereed  that @Hit's

Answer (score 1):

You have some error in your custom module. I have the same issue and it was due to issue in `module.xml` file. Can you please remove/disable your custom modules one by one to verify it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer +1 i will look in to that.

Answer (score 1):

> Try the below, it should work.

- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento setup:di:compile
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
- php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: thanks for the answer +1 for that, i already tried all above commands

Answer (score 1):

For find out problem you may go to your log file and you can check your error. or run `setup:di:compile` command to find out problem.

I think there is problem with your `module.xml` file in your any module. because there might be chance a mistake to write module name or setup version.

I hope it helpes!.

Comment: hahah :) compare your git file with any existing running enterprise cloud project.

Comment: Try to run `composer:update` and check.

Comment: already did that too